# Apps installed on external SD card and web shortcuts dissapeared from home screen after reboot

Tags: android, sd-card

I have set the phone to install the apps on the external SD card. After a reboot all the icons of the apps installed on the external SD card dissapeared from home screen. Also, all the web shortcuts dissapeared and it is not possible to add them again (I guess the launcher checks to see if the shortcut already exists).

Comment: Your current issue aside - I really would reconsider the wisdom of keeping apps [or anything important] on SD, unless they are disposable or you have backups.

Comment: why not? why are apps important? you can reinstall them, no? In my case is not really a choice as I don't have enough space on the phone to install all the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go in Settings, Apps, All.
2. Look for the app named Launcher*.
3. Tap on it and then tap on Force stop.
4. The launcher restarts and all icons are restored.

Why I think it works: while booting, the external sd card is not mounted yet when the launcher checks what icons it has to display. After the boot is completed, the sd card is mounted and so the launcher has access to all icons. All you have to do is to force it to read them again with a force stop.